# GitLab Permissions

Tags: gitlab

I would like to enable a group of users to fork any repo from a GitLab group and subsequently send PR's to repos in that GitLab group but not be able to push to repos in that GitLab group.

Is this possible using one of the standard access levels; Guest/Reporter/Developer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the 'Reporter' access level does exactly what I need.

What I did was;

- Grant one user group Owner access to the repo group (the release managers in my context)
- Grant another user group Reporter access to the repo group (the feature devs)

The release managers now have full access, the feature devs can fork and send PR's (merge requests in GL vocab).

Answer (score 2):

You can set yourself as the only one with write access:

[image]

That way, many people can send pull requests to your branch, but only you can merge them.